# how to create mail merge style report using jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using ireport 4.1.1 and want to create mail merge style report.

the required format looks like this

```
student id,
student name,
student address,
```

> Dear parent,
>
> There is an outstanding balance of balance_amount which needs to 
>   be paid by balance_date.
>
> Sincerely,
>   Debt set of officer.

Comment: I dint try. even i don't have idea also how to do it.so i am asking for help.

Comment: Hi Mr Kumar, welcome to StackOverflow! It is recommended that you try and put some effort into a problem. SO is typically for asking if you get stuck somewhere. Cheers!

Comment: I dont have idea how to do it.any ideas, how can i create such report?

Comment: I am not a java guy ,any ideas, how can i create such report? i know only sql part.

Comment: @harishkumar Have you ever created report with iReport?
If so, I think it's not difficult to show data from DB.
If you haven't used iReport yet, try to start create simple report.

Comment: The format that you required is this? [how to create mail merge style report using jasper reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/850401/how-create-mail-merge-style-report-using-jasper-reports)

Comment: Yes you are right yasuyuki,can you help me in the same? I am a sql guy.

Comment: Maybe I can help you.
But I don't want write here tutorial of create report and call from Java, if possible.
Can you put StaticText and TextField to create report?
Can you call sql query from iReport?
I don't know what you can and what you can't.

Comment: Yes i know how to put static text and text field in jasper report and also i know how to call sql query from jasper ireport. i know about jasper ireport tool.

Comment: So, you can create report. OK.
What problem that you're facing is "How to call your report from Java" ?

Comment: Yes ... i don't know how to call report from java.help me in java part.

Comment: OK, allright. I posted answer.
However, your question is unclear.
I suggest you to edit your question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call jasper from Java, how about below code?

```
 String jasperPath = context.getRealPath("yourreport.jasper");
 String PdfPath = context.getRealPath("your pdf output path");

 // Load your jasper file.
 JasperReport jasper = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(jasperPath);

 // If you want to pass params, set value here.
 Map paramMap = new HashMap();
 paramMap.put("report_title", "The Title");

 // I usually create sql query dynamically and pass as param. If you'll use static query, needless to pass.
 // paramMap.put("w_sql", "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ");

 JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasper, paramMap, connection);

 // Export to PDF
 JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, PdfPath);
```

Also you have to add some libraries(jasperreports-X.X.X.jar, iText-X.X.X.jar, and so on) at your project lib directory, and set classpath.
In my case, I'm using iReport3.6.1.

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WEB-INF/lib/xalan.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WEB-INF/lib/commons-digester-1.7.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WEB-INF/lib/groovy-all-1.5.5.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WEB-INF/lib/iText-2.1.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WEB-INF/lib/iTextAsian.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WEB-INF/lib/jasperreports-3.6.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="WEB-INF/lib/barbecue-1.5-beta1.jar"/>
```